# facebook login script stopped working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I dont know what happened to my script, it was working great, then it suddenly doesnt return email (returns undefined), but the firstname, lastname and username work fine.

here is the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


      // initialize the library with the API key

      FB.init({  appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

      function login() {
          FB.login(function (response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

                  FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.email :' + response.email);
                      console.log('Good to see you, ' + ",gender:" + response.gender + "another : " + response.first_name);
                      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.username + '.last_name :' + response.last_name);
                    //  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response);
                  }, { scope: 'email' });
              } else {
                  console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
              }
          });
      }
  </script>
```

I havent changed anything though, what could be wrong ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I login to facebook, it only asks for basic info access permission, doesnt mention email at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the email, `{ scope: 'email' }` needs to be be passed to [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), not as a parameter to `FB.api`.

```
FB.login(function (response) {
   ...
}, { scope: 'email' });
```